# Spring injection issue with constructor-arg overload

Tags: java, spring, code-injection, constructor-injection, spring-bean

I would like to ask about the Spring Constructor Injection.
So in the class, I have two constructors with different number of arguments.

```
public class MyClassHello() {
    public MyClassHello(String A) {
        // do sth
    }

    public MyClassHello(String A, int B){
        // do sth
    }
}
```

If I try to inject like this to access the 1st constructor, Spring can not work since there is ambiguity.

```
<bean id="injectQuestion" class="MyClassHello">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="A String"/>
</bean>
```

The debug code is like this:

```
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 1 of type [java.lang.String]: Ambiguous constructor argument types.
```

I think it means, Spring needs to know if the index 1 argument exists?

It is not like the usual case where we have two constructors with same number of arguments. Like that, I could set the type in order to distinguish when injecting.

In my case, is there anyway to force Spring to choose the first constructor?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: While I find this odd that your current setup will cause any ambiguity, add a `type` attribute to your constructor definition to clear up any remaining ambiguity. You should then have `<constructor-arg index ="0" type="java.lang.String" value="A String"/>`

Comment: @kolossus That won't help, I already tried but still the same result. For both constructor the 1st argument is a string. The problem I think is how the injection know whether the 2nd argument exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the name:

```
<bean id= "InjectQuestion" class = "MyClassHello">
    <constructor-arg name = "A" value="A String"/>
</bean>

<bean id= "InjectQuestion" class = "MyClassHello">
    <constructor-arg name = "A" value="A String"/>
    <constructor-arg name = "B" value="42"/>
</bean>
```

Note that your syntax in declaring the class is not valid; and also when defining the bean, in `class="..."` you should use the fully qualified name of the class (for example `packageName.subPackage.MyClassHello` not just `MyClassHello`)

Comment: Thanks. I will have a try. Sorry for the syntax.